# Is there a dart function annotation that makes the type checker do type narrowing or condition assertions

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a construct that communicates to the type checker a function's post-condition?

For example, in typescript it is possible to say

```js
function assertIsNumber(value: any): asserts value is number {
  if (typeof value !== 'number') {
    throw new TypeError();
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like the following in dart:

```dart
class SomeClass {
    int? value;

    _checkPreconditions() {
        if(value == null) {
            throw MyPreconditionError()
        }
        // ...
    }

    somefunc() {
        _checkPreconditions();
        // here we know `value` is a non-null int.
        final sum = value + 5;
    }
}
```

I understand I could coerce the value to non-null `sum = value! + 5`, but I would prefer to allow the function to inform the type checker if possible.

Comment: you can `assert(value!=null);` although it will only work in debug mode. See [assert](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert) in the language tour. Does this satisfies your answer or your needs are more specific?

Comment: @croxx5f.  Thanks for the response.  As far as I understand it, assert does not allow a function call like `_checkPreconditions()`, in the example above, to affect the type checker.

Comment: You can call functions on assert but they wont  promote the value type. Even calling a function like `_checkPreconditions` won't  promote your values. There are some limited workarounds like using the builder pattern but depending on the amount of attributes you check it can get out of hands quickly.

Comment: Ah, too bad.  I was hoping the type checker was more flexible. Thanks for clarifying.  The builder is a good point.  I don't think I would prefer it for this use case but worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @croxx5f [`assert(value != null)` will not promote `value` to a non-null type](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36883).  Using `value!` later will still be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the type system of Dart is not so powerful. The only thing that looks (from first glance) possible is to create a custom code analyzer package (or search for one that already exists).

Answer (score 1):

Dart annotations don't actually *do* anything.  They provide hints to tools such as the Dart *analyzer* (usually so that it can generate additional warnings), but they cannot change program behavior.  Even if you could convince the analyzer to treat some variables as different types, you still wouldn't be able to compile and run your code.

Annotations can be used by code generation tools, so one possibility might be to generate a statement such as `final value = this.value!;` automatically.  However, that would be a lot of trouble to go through (and would mean that code then would need to use `this.value = 42;` for assignments and would prevent your code from being analyzed directly).